# Linear combination on $\mathbb R_{1} \left[ x \right ]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the canonical basis of $\mathbb R_{1} [ x ]$,  $\{x,1\}$, I tryed to write each vector as a linear combination of the basis $B=\{3x+6,2x+10\}$.

So, I started by $x$.

$x=\lambda_{1}(3x+6)+\lambda_{2}(2x+10)=(3\lambda_{1}+2\lambda_{2})x+6\lambda_{1}+10\lambda_{2}$

Then I solved the system by a matrix,

$\begin{bmatrix}
 3&2\\6&10
\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}
 \lambda_{1}\\\lambda_{2}
\end{bmatrix}$=
$\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\0
\end{bmatrix}$

The result was $\lambda_{1}=\frac{5}{9}$ and $\lambda_{2}=-\frac{1}{3}$.

But now I don't know how to define the coordinates of $x$ on the basis $B$. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have $\langle1,0 \rangle^T$, you want to solve for $\langle 0,1\rangle^T$, which you would do similarly:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}3&2\\6&10\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mu_1\\\mu_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} $$

Which implies $\langle\mu_1,\mu_2\rangle^T=\left\langle-\frac19,\frac16\right\rangle^T$

Now, given any vector $\langle x,y\rangle^T$ in the original basis, we have

$$ x\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\to x\begin{pmatrix}\frac59\\-\frac13\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}-\frac19\\\frac16\end{pmatrix}=\frac1{18}\begin{pmatrix}10x-2y\\-6x+3y\end{pmatrix} $$
And that's the vector under the new basis (note that this is really just the matrix inverse of the basis change).

Comment: I thought that the coordinates of $x$ in the basis $B$ would be something like $ax+b$, which would be a vector span by $B$.

Comment: No offense, but since when are $2$-D coordinates $ax+b$?  And one vector can't span a basis with two linearly independent vectors. If you want $x$ coordinates you simply need to do the following: $y=0$ implies that $\begin{pmatrix}x\\0\end{pmatrix}$ transforms to $\begin{pmatrix}\frac59x\\-\frac13x\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, then $x$ written in the basis $B$ simply has the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{5}{9} & -\frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix}. $$
This is analogous to the fact that the basis vectors of $B$ have the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix} \quad\text{and}\quad \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 10 \end{pmatrix} $$
when written in the canonical base $(\,x,\, 1\,)$.

Answer (score -1):

The coordinates of $x$ should be your $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$. You have already changed its basis to be written in terms of vectors in $B$ rather than vectors in the standard basis.

$$
[x]_{\{x,1\}} = (1, 0) \\
[x]_{B} = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2)
$$